# How to get analytics of a specific video of youtube daywise in java?

Tags: java, youtube-api, youtube-analytics

I have used you tube analytics api in which i can get analytics of channel and content owners by daywise but i want to get analytics of a specific video of youtube daywise. How to get it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Here](https://developers.google.com/youtube/analytics/v1/channel_reports#Reports) you will find a list of filters for a request to the Youtube Analytics API, among which the ***video*** which takes the id of the video you want to see the analytics for.

Orient yourself further through the documentation for more answer and examples.